# Jenkins exit 0 (без ошибок)

Tags: jenkins

Добрый день.
Запускаю из Jenkins заглушку, посредством команды (`java -jar namezagl.jar`)
Джоб успешно собирается и останавливается, хотя заглушка циклическая и должна работать до принудительной остановки, в выводе консоли указано:

```
11:17:51.424 [main] DEBUG utils.Main.main - Application started
D:\tools\.jenkins\workspace\4Testing2\Main_TB13>exit 0 
Finished: SUCCESS
```

`11:17:51.424 [main] DEBUG utils.Main.main - Application started` - это хорошо, так и должно быть.
Но вот почему потом exit 0 и всё???

При том, если я запускаю этот же джарник у себя через CMD - всё отлично, никаких проблем.

Comment: `никаких проблем` – проблем нет, а что есть? Что вы ожидаете после запуска вместо `exit 0`?

Comment: Заглушка должна постоянно работать. Когда в очередь MQ придёт сообщение, она его обработает и ответит. А так она остановилась совсем.
Если я запускаю через CMD - она, как и должна, ждёт свои сообщения, не закрывается.

Comment: а вы в CMD `exit 0` пишите?

Comment: попробуй запустить джаву через nohup java -jar.